# rails ajax post not saving session variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, session

Controller is not updating session params when responding to an ajax request. I spent an hour on this and still have no idea why this is happening. Have I missed something super important about ajax?

Crontroller logs being hit and changing session var

```
def update
 if params["commit"] == "Generate Validation Code"
  Rails.logger.info "session before: #{session[:last_validation]}"
  session[:last_validation] = Time.now.to_i
  Rails.logger.info "session after: #{session[:last_validation]}"
 end
end
```

Non-ajax request - session var updated and saved correctly

```
<%= form_for @ignindex do |t| %>
  <%= t.submit "Generate Validation Code", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Ajax request - controller shows session var updated, but it never gets saved?

```
$.ajax({
 url: "/ignindices/" + $("#ign").data("id"),
 type: "PUT",
 data: {"commit" : "Generate Validation Code" },
 dataType: "json",
 success: function(data) {
    console.log("it submitted!");
   }
 });
```

Comment: Struggling with the same issue myself (1 yr later).  I'm sure it has something to do with the round-trip of the session / cookie and the fact that it isn't happening (or is possibly being overridden).  If I add a redirect (`window.location = /somewhere/else` in the `success` callback it will update the `session[]`.  However, this isn't particularly helpful if you don't want to redirect.

Comment: The solution was use unobtrusive javascript in rails :p. Also the controller was expecting a csrf token, generated with the `form_for` but missing in the ajax put